# Why string_view constructor doesn't take a pair of iterators

Tags: c++, string-view, string-span

Both string_ref in boost and string_span in GSL doesn't define constructor that takes a pair of iterator. What is the reason of this decision ?

Usually it's not a big deal, I can just create string_ref like this :

```
boost::string_ref s(start, std::distance(start, finish));
```

but the reason I want constructor that take a pair of iterators is because I have code that look like this:

```
template<typename Type, typename Iterator>
void func(const Iterator& begin, const Iterator& end)
{
    Type s(begin, end);
    //do stuff with s
}
```

Currently, I can call it like this :

```
func<std::string>(start, finish)
```

I want to change it to :

```
func<boost::string_ref>(start, finish) //compile error
```

but that code won't compile because the lack of constructor taking a pair of iterator in string_ref

Comment: I'm assuming that your iterators are in fact `std::string::iterator` ? Because `string_ref` references an existing string, so you can't construct it from thin air.

Comment: @MSalters Actually, my iterator are already `boost::string_ref::iterator` :).

Comment: A worth reading chat about this was done at the std future proposal group: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/6X6_IjfzdYI , worth the read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I make a mistake. `gsl::string_span` do have a constructor that takes begin and end iterator. So, there is nothing problematic with creating string_view from iterator pairs and the lack of it in `boost::string_ref` is probably just an oversight.

For my case, I end up inheriting from `boost::string_ref` and add the constructor myself.

Answer (score 5):

`boost::string_ref` is a simple reference to a string in the form of a pointer to a *contiguous* block of memory with a predefined length. Since iterators are much more generic, you cannot assume that your `start, finish` range refers to anything like a contiguous block of memory.

On the other hand, a `std::string` can be constructed from a range defined by Iterators because it will simply make a copy of the range's values, regardless of what the underlying data structure is.

Comment: That's not actually a wholly convincing argument. It would be reasonable to construct a `boost::string_ref` from a `std::string::iterator`. But even that is not allowed.

Comment: @MSalters Exactly, at the very least they should be able to accept a pair of `boost::string_ref::iterator`

Answer (score 2):

Helper function I created, hopefully someone else can find this useful.  Briefly tested MSVC14/boost 1.59, MSVC17/boost 1.64, MSVC17/C++17

```
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

// todo:  change to std::basic_string_view<charT> in C++17
template <typename charT> using basic_string_view_type = boost::basic_string_ref<charT>;    

// Creates a string view from a pair of iterators
//  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33750600/882436
template <typename _It>
inline constexpr auto make_string_view( _It begin, _It end )
{
    using result_type = basic_string_view_type<typename std::iterator_traits<_It>::value_type>;

    return result_type{
        ( begin != end ) ? &*begin : nullptr
        ,  (typename result_type::size_type)
        std::max(
            std::distance(begin, end)
            , (typename result_type::difference_type)0
        )
     };
}   // make_string_view
```

Comment: I just fell into the corner case: if `begin == end` and they are not dereferenceable (i.e. they both point at the end of a string) then `&*begin` causes UB.

Comment: @Quentin -- good catch, I updated my post to correct that issue, thank you.  Now it's just returning an empty string view when begin==end